# Почему блок вылезает за контейнер? Как затемнить фон при наведении?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, frontend

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Team */

.team {
 margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.team__inner {
 text-align: center;
}

.team__title {
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 font-weight: 600;
 color: #12C2E9;
 
 margin-bottom: 11.2px;
}

.team__suptitle {
 font-size: 2rem;
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: 700;
}

.team__suptitle:after {
 content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 50px auto;

    background: linear-gradient(to right, #E100FF, #F80759);
}

.team__team {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}

.team__item {
 position: relative;
 
 margin-left: 20px;
}

.team__item:hover .team__photo-about {
 display: block;
}

.team__item:first-child {
 margin-left: 0;
}

.team__photo {
 max-width: 100%;
}

.team__photo-about {
 display: none;
 
 margin-bottom: 22px;
 
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 z-index: 1;
}

.team__name {
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 font-weight: 600;
 color: #fff;
}

.team__prof {
 font-size: 0.8rem;
 color: #12C2E9;
}
```

```html
<div class="team">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="team__inner">
   <h2 class="team__title">Meet</h2>
   <h1 class="team__suptitle">OUR TRAINERS</h1>
   
   <div class="team__team">
   
    <div class="team__item">
    
     <div class="team__photo">
      <img src="images/Team/Trainer%201.jpg" alt="">
     </div>
     
     <div class="team__photo-about">
      <h1 class="team__name">Letty Adams</h1>
      <h2 class="team__prof">Fitness Trainer</h2>
     </div>
     
    </div>

    <div class="team__item">
    
     <div class="team__photo">
      <img src="images/Team/Trainer%202.jpg" alt="">
     </div>
     
     <div class="team__photo-about">
      <h1 class="team__name">Letty Adams</h1>
      <h2 class="team__prof">Fitness Trainer</h2>
     </div>
     
    </div>

    <div class="team__item">
    
     <div class="team__photo">
      <img src="images/Team/Trainer%203.jpg" alt="">
     </div>
     
     <div class="team__photo-about">
      <h1 class="team__name">Letty Adams</h1>
      <h2 class="team__prof">Fitness Trainer</h2>
     </div>
     
    </div>

    <div class="team__item">
    
     <div class="team__photo">
      <img src="images/Team/Trainer%204.jpg" alt="">
     </div>
     
     <div class="team__photo-about">
      <h1 class="team__name">Letty Adams</h1>
      <h2 class="team__prof">Fitness Trainer</h2>
     </div>
     
    </div>

    <div class="team__item">
    
     <div class="team__photo">
      <img src="images/Team/Trainer%205.jpg" alt="">
     </div>
     
     <div class="team__photo-about">
      <h1 class="team__name">Letty Adams</h1>
      <h2 class="team__prof">Fitness Trainer</h2>
     </div>
     
    </div>
   </div> <!-- ./team__team -->
   
  </div> <!-- ./team__inner -->
 </div> <!-- ./container -->
</div> <!-- ./team -->
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Блок вылезает за контейнер, как это исправить?
После слов Learn More блок team выходит за контейнер.

Comment: Предполагаю, что размер контейнера равен верхнему, там где заканчивается learn more?

Comment: Denis640Kb, да.

Comment: для картинок max-width: 100%.

Comment: Serednity, ничего не изменилось

Comment: @CreatorGod выложите, пожалуйста, код. Вы уверены, что оба блока находятся в одном контейнере?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А у вас точно размер контейнер с картинками такой же как и у блока вверху? Сюдя по скрину он больше. У вас блок с картинками отцентрирован. Если бы размер был такой же то левая картинка была бы на уровне 'learn more', а справа вылазила б.

Затемнение блока при ховере:

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.block:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #000;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.block:hover:after {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо, затемнение фона сработало. да, блок выше был меньше, а нижний был нужной длины. спасибо.